# How can a farmstead be situated in its paddock?

Tags: the-markenmore-mystery, j-s-fletcher

In *[The Markenmore Mystery](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/59818/59818-h/59818-h.htm#toc1)* (1922) by J. S. Fletcher, the author was describing Markenmore village:

> Markenmore was a place of tiny thatched cottages, set in gardens and orchards, with here and there a substantial farmstead, set back from the road, in **its** paddock or home-garth; its main feature stood in its midst—a grey old church, whose tower and spire rose high above the elms and poplars that fenced in the churchyard.

I think that the bolded "its" refers to [the farmstead](https://www.lexico.com/definition/farmstead), but how can the farmstead, which is the larger thing, be situated in its paddock or home-garth, which is just a part from it?

Comment: This type of question about the meaning of everyday words would be better asked on the English Language learners stack exchange - https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the *farmstead* here refers to the buildings on the farm, while the *paddock* refers to the fenced-in land associated with the farm. The definition in the OED is.

> A plot of farmland and the buildings upon it; a homestead; a farmhouse and its adjacent outbuildings.

The third of these possibilities seems to limit the definition of *farmstead* to just the farm's building, while there could be a lot of additional fenced-in grazing land, which would be the *paddock*.